# Property [owner] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationships

I'm having a bit of difficulty grasping exactly what Laravel is trying to communicate here and how Eloquent is building/attaching these relationships.

`Property [owner] does not exist on this collection instance.`

I'm creating a customer support inbox where customers can send tickets in and administrators can respond back.

I'd like to be able to pull the name & some details of the user in the message so, well, the rep knows who they are talking to.  Currently there are three tables in play: `tickets, users, & replies`.  I'll break down the structure here as well:

```
Tickets: id, user_id, body, active (boolean), datestuff... | relates to the Ticket model
replies: id, user_id, ticket_id, body, datestuff | relates to the Reply model.
```

I've defined the relationship in the Ticket model of `$this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id');` via a public method of `owner`

```
public function owner()
    {
        // ESTABLISH RELATIONSHIP

        $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');

    }
```

But when I attempt to retrieve the below I retrieve the error in the title.  From the TicketsController

```
$tickets = Ticket::latest()->get();
return $tickets->owner;
```

And am unable to `{{ $ticket->owner->first_name }}` or any details on the user that I'd like to pull.

Either my fundamental understanding of Eloquent is incorrect or there are other things that need to be assigned in order to enable this functionality?

I was following along with this episode from Laracast here substituting the Thread for Ticket but Reply namespace stayed.  Though Instead of retrieving the user data associated with the reply I'm retrieving the user data of the initial ticket.

https://laracasts.com/series/lets-build-a-forum-with-laravel/episodes/3

Comment: firstly you need to use return to return the relation object and second you have to tell eloquent about ids to user which are table1name.id, tablename2.id if both are not named after tables names so
return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'table1name.id', 'tablename2.id');

Comment: Try **$Ticket = Ticket::with("owner")->latest()->get();**  then try $Ticket->owner

Comment: If you would like to retrive specific information from user table then you can try like this $Ticket = Ticket::with(["owner" => function($q){ return $q->select("..","..");}]->latest ()->get();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tickets = Ticket::latest()->get();
return $tickets->owner;
```

This code grabs a *collection* of tickets. **Each** ticket in that collection has its *own* owner.

```
foreach($tickets as $ticket) {
    // this is where you have $ticket->owner;
}
```

Your `owner()` function is also not *returning* the relationship - it creates one, but does nothing with it. This'll work:

```
public function owner() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

Comment: Then after running that: {{ $ticket->owner }}} in the view file.  I'm retrieving a 
`App\Ticket::owner must return a relationship instance.` error :( So it looks like the relationship is failing to instance?

Comment: @IanBuss That's because your `public function owner()` doesn't `return` anything. It needs to `return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');` Added that to my answer.

Comment: **internal screaming as I've been trying to figure this out for about two days now you are the best :) **

Comment: Definitely been there. Glad I could help!